# Taylor series expansion of $f(x_0+h, z_0+k_1)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to understand the taylor series expansion of $f(x_0+h, z_0+k_1)$

It is given by:

$f(x_0+h, z_0+k_1)= f(x_0, z_0)+ h*\frac{\partial f(x_0, z_0)}{\partial x}+ k_1*\frac{\partial f(x_0, z_0)}{\partial y}+...$

But what is the general rule? I can't find it.

Comment: Try to first write the Taylor expansion only in h, keeping $z_0 + k_1$ unchanged in the second argument. Then expand each of those terms in $k_1$.

Comment: I do not understand, can you give the example?

Comment: $$f(x_0+h,z_0+k_1) = f(x_0,z_0+k_1) + h \partial_x f(x_0,z_0+k_1) + \tfrac{1}{2} h^2 \partial_x^2 f(x_0,z_0+k_1) + O(h^3)$$ That is the first step. Now for each of the terms, you can do a Taylor expansion in the second argument again. This way you can obtain as many terms as you need.